# Unique Random Integer Generator

Tags: java, random, integer, unique

I'm trying to make a random Integer generator that produces unique numbers.

Does anyone has any ideas how's that possible?

Comment: I do, but you should show that you have actually tried something...

Comment: @MitchWheat doesn't uniqueness means it won't be truly random?

Comment: What do you mean by unique, globally unique, or just once you've personally created it you don't want annother one the same

Comment: Maybe the poster wants a GUID?

Comment: @Thihara The sequence as a whole will be a random permutation of a finite set.

Comment: By unique I mean that I want all random numbers to be diferent from eachother.

Comment: But its not the case that (for example) you have 100 customers and need your application running on their computers to be able to produce identifiers unique for all 99 other customers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a small-enough range of possible numbers, then this is very simple and useful:

```
final List<Integer> sack = new ArrayList<>(RANGE);
for (int i = 0; i < RANGE; i++) sack.add(i);
Collections.shuffle(sack);
```

Now just pull items out of `sack` in order.

Answer (score 1):

One simple algorithm would be:

1. create a `HashSet<Integer> set`
2. generate a random number
3. if not present in `set` => use that random number and store it in `set`
4. if present in `set`, return to step 2

Note that the numbers won't be truly random because of the uniqueness constraint.

Comment: This is only to be recommended it you don't plan to exhaust the set because the performance painfully degrades as the unstruck numbers get scanty.

Answer (score 1):

If what you're looking for is globally unique identifier you might want to consider java's UUID class that produces an ID that will only be created once, ever, across the whole world

```
import java.util.UUID;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(UUID.randomUUID());
    }
}
```

It is, however, alphanumeric not an integer

Comment: @user2375278 lol, fair enough. You see now why I wanted to know exactly what you meant by unique

Answer (score 0):

There is not such thing like unique integer random.

You are limited in the best case to number 2 to power of 64 witch is quite big number.

The problem with unique values is for what do you need them. Do they have to be unique for single application run or do they must stay unique for whole application life ?

So you will have bunch of way to create a random number generator. The UUID is a option but the assyliasaproach is fine too also the `Fisher-Yates shuffle` is quite good example.

To this collection you can add something like.

1. Create a container
2. Put in it n integer in order.
3. Shuffle the items in container.
4. Read elements form it in order.

If you have choose as container a List you can shuffle it using  [Collections.shuffle()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Random%29)