# How to generate an array of pseudo-random, unique, sorted integers without using an if statement?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, for-loop, if-statement

I need to create an array of pseudo-random unique integers that are already in an ascending order without using an if statement. For example:

```
[3,5,7,12]
```

So far I was able to come up with this code, which repeats some numbers and doesn't put the integers in sorted order.

```java
int[] arr = new int[r.nextInt(10)];
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    int randInt = r.nextInt(arr.length);
    arr[i] = randInt;
}
```

What is the best way to work around this? *Note:* I have to not use the `ArrayList` and `sort` method.

Comment: You could use a binary tree. Then you have the check if a value already exists and the insertion in sorted order all in a single transaction with *O(log n)* complexity.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unique Random Integer Generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16519022/unique-random-integer-generator) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039025/java-array-of-unique-randomly-generated-integers  or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25012033/add-unique-random-numbers-to-an-integer-array. Maybe next time you can search before you ask

Comment: `while (condition) {  /* code */ break; }` kind of works like an `if` (and good to confuse any reader)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add the previous random number and add to the current random number to ensure that it is greater than the previous one. If you want to have a bound on the random number then you could use `nextInt(int bound)`. I would recommend the use of a bound to avoid any possible overflows.

```java
Random r = new Random();
int prev = r.nextInt(); // seed value may or may not be added to list.
int size = 10; // desired size of random list
int[] rands = new int[size];
int bound = 1000;

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    // this ensures that new number is always greater than the previous one
    rands[i] = (prev + 1) + r.nextInt(bound);
    prev = rand[i];
}
```

If all the numbers needs to be in a given range, we need to use arithmetic progression formula.
`aN = a +(n-1) d`. we need to compute the `d` and add this to the previous random number to ensure the new number is greater.

So in a normal arithmetic progression, starting from `a` if we keep on adding `d`, `n` times, then we would surely reach `aN`. So to generate a random ascending series such that the last number is less than or equal to `aN`, we need to add a random number that is less than or equal to `d` and greater than 0 (to ensure uniqueness of series elements). So we add `nextInt(d) + 1` during each iteration.

```java
Random r = new Random();
int aN = 20; // desired max value
int n = 10; // desired size of random list
int[] rands = new int[n];

int seed = r.nextInt(aN / 2); // divide by 2 to ensure it is not close to aN
int d = (aN - seed) / (n - 1);
// This d would be passed to the prev random number to get the new random number.
// This ensures that that last element never crosses the max range even if
// `nextInt` returns the maximum possible value (d-1).

rands[0] = seed;
int prev = seed;
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    rands[i] = prev + r.nextInt(d) + 1;
    prev = rand[i];
}
```

Comment: wow, this is genius! But can you give me a hint if I want the random numbers in the array to be within some range: for example from 0 to 20? like [1,2,5,12,18, 19]

Comment: @dwin812 i have added one. But it is not foolproof without using an `if` condition. This is because `nextInt` could return a very small number including a 0. So, to ensure uniqueness we might need to use an `if`

Comment: @dwin812 i have updated that answer. check it out now

Comment: @GauthamM - You do not need `temp`. You can simply write `rands[i] = (prev + 1) + r.nextInt(bound); prev = rands[i];`

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Yes, i just used temp to focus on the operation

Answer (score 1):

*Without `ArrayList` and `sort` method*: you can use [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html), which provides ascending order for *integers* and guarantees unique values:

```java
TreeSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>();
while (set.size() < 10) {
    set.add((int) (1 + Math.random() * 100));
}

int[] arr = set.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
// [15, 20, 30, 42, 46, 55, 59, 63, 92, 98]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an instance of `Random` and stream the values.

```
Random r = new Random();
int min = 1;
int max = 20_000;
int count = 19_999;
int[] vals =
        r.ints(min, max).distinct().limit(count).sorted().toArray();
```

The above works fairly fast on my machine but it is not very efficient (especially since in that case you have all the integers from 1 to count in sorted order).

It is imperative that `count <= max-min` or it will never finish executing since eventually, no subsequent value generated will ever be distinct.  And as `max-min - count` increases, so does the efficiency.  It's related to the  [Pigeonhole Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle#:%7E:text=If%20there%20are%20n%20people,hands%20shaken%20by%20that%20person.).

A more realistic example might be

```
int[] vals =
        r.ints(1, 100).distinct().limit(10).sorted().toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(vals));
```

Prints

```
[9, 15, 18, 45, 68, 70, 72, 74, 95, 96]
```